# Run jasmine test against many websites

Tags: javascript, jasmine, webdriver-io

I am testing a web filter and would like to run a simple test to verify that a page is blocked. I would also like to run this test on hundreds of pages. The following code works for a individual page:

```
for (var n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
     describe("Blocked Sites", () => {

        it('should block ', () => {
            sites.pageGo();
            expect(sites.blockedIDOnLoad.isVisible()).toBeTruthy;
        });

    });
```

}

sites.pageGo() provides the next site each time the loop is repeated. This works great as long as every page provided by pageGo() is blocked. For example if it loops 3 times I will get 3 passing tests. I can watch as the browser loads each different page and gets blocked. However if any of the pages are not blocked, all tests fail. I would like to run this test against many sites (some blocked, some not). I am a beginner when it comes to automated testing, and I would very much appreciate any guidance/knowledge you have to offer. Is there a way to implement this test with my current framework, or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by using a for...of loop. Here is what worked for me. Hope this helps.

First I setup a site class.

```
export default class Site {
    url: string;
    id: string;

    constructor(url: string, id: string) {
        this.url = url;
        this.id = id;
     }

    get blockedIDOnLoad() { return browser.element(this.id); }    
}
```

And then the tests look like this...

```
import site from './site';

describe("Blocked Sites", () => {
    //obviously you wouldn't do it this way for a bunch of sites
    //should help get the idea across though
    const sites = [ new site("http://www.google.com", "#lst-ib"),
        new site("http://facebook.com", "#blockedId"),
        new site("http://twitter.com", "#blockedId") ];    

    for (const s of sites) {
        it('should block', () => {
            browser.url(s.url);
            expect(s.blockedIDOnLoad.isVisible()).toBe(true);
        });            
    }
});
```

The google test passes because that is a valid id on that page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use [this](https://javascript.info/testing-mocha) as below

```
describe("test power", () => {

       function test(x){
       var result = x * x * x;
       it(`${x} in the power 3 is ${result}`, function() {
       assert.equal(pow(x, 3), result);
    });
       for (var x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
    test(x);
  }  
}

});
```